# Font Awesome 4 Menus

Tags: wordpress, font-awesome

I am running Font Awesome 4 Menus V 4.2.0.1 and having issues with the Yelp icon.

I have Facebook (fa-facebook fa-2x) and Instagram (fa-instagram fa-2x) working properly, but when I try to use the css code for Yelp (fa-yelp fa-2x), the icon does not appear.

Could this be because the plugin is not working well with the latest update to Font Awesome (4.2).

Any advice would be helpful.

Take a look at our staging site at http://s440588831.onlinehome.us/DailyHarvestMarket/.

https://wordpress.org/plugins/font-awesome-4-menus/

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your theme is overriding the Font Awesome 4 Menus plugin. The Font Awesome 4 Menus is loading the latest stylesheet (4.2.0) from MaxCDN, but then the Canvas theme is overriding that by loading an older version of Font Awesome (4.0.3) in which fa-yelp is not available.

Because the Canvas theme loads Font Awesome directly in its stylesheet, you need to either delete that from the stylesheet or ask the theme author to update to the latest version of Font Awesome (and then tell Font Awesome 4 Menus not to also load the stylesheet, which you can do through the admin panel).